# How to stop my eventlisteners from stacking in the body class?

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, addeventlistener

I've written a code that instead of incorporating a light/dark mode, it incorporates a spring/summer/autumn/winter mode.
Here is an example of one season:

```
const springThemeOn = sessionStorage.getItem("springtheme")
if (springThemeOn==="true"){
    document.body.className = "spring-theme";
    spring.classList.add('hide-icon');
    summer.classList.remove('hide-icon');
    autumn.classList.remove('hide-icon');
    winter.classList.remove('hide-icon');
}

//spring change
springIcon.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle('spring-theme');
    spring.classList.toggle('show-icon');
    summer.classList.toggle('show-icon');
    autumn.classList.toggle('show-icon');
    winter.classList.toggle('show-icon');
    // Store toggle info between pages
    if (document.body.className.includes("spring-theme")){
        // Currently in spring mode
        sessionStorage.setItem("spring-theme", "true")
    } else {
        // Currently in other mode
        sessionStorage.setItem("spring-theme", "false")
    }
})
```

Imagine this with all four seasons.
The code works, but when I click on each icon respectively, they each add themselves to the body class like so: `<body class="b-page spring-theme summer-theme autumn-theme winter-theme">` and only displays the last clicked on mode.

I want to be able to switch through all four icons and not have to click on/off each icon in order to add/remove them from the class body. I do not want them to stack in the class body. Is there a fix for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a storage item for each theme, have them all share a single storage item.

```
const theme = sessionStorage.getItem("theme");
if (theme === 'spring') {
  // ...
} else if (theme === 'summer') {
  // ...
}
// etc
```

And in the click listener, something like:

```
if (document.body.className.includes("spring-theme")){
    sessionStorage.setItem('theme', ''); // remove any existing themes
} else {
    sessionStorage.setItem('theme', 'spring'); // add it
}
```

This way, there won't be any collisions.

Comment: Hi I appreciate your reply! Sadly I tried your way but they still appear to be stacking/adding together in the body class :( will try some different combos and see if I can find a solution. Thank you anyways.

Comment: When the theme changes, set the class to the new theme only - don't try to keep the old class. Eg, do `document.body.className = newTheme` where `newTheme` is the same value you set to `sessionStorage`.